Book about a dystopian world where people plug into a server with headsets and have silver swirls around their eyes being special
I read this book when I was really young so I can’t be sure about all the details, but it was around 2014 when I read it. The cover was white, I think, with silver or black swirls around an eye
It was about some dystopian world where a girl lays on a couch and puts on this headset that plugs her into a virtual world but she doesn’t feel right about it. She meets a guy who tells her she’s special and that they both (and others like them) have silver whorls around their eyes and temples. In the end she finds out this guy she met is just a brain in a tank when she goes to save him. I can’t say if it’s a series.

When you say "a brain in a tank" do you mean a tank in a research lab or do you mean like a battle tank with guns etc?

@DannyMcG - I'm assuming she means that he's in a jar rather than being a Bolo

@DannyMcG like a research lab, although a brain in an armoured tank would be pretty funny
